# Assign post to custom user role

Tags: wordpress, admin, custom-post-type, user-roles

I created custom user role for my project, and want to admin assign post for some user with custom user role, but in wp-admin when I go to create new post, I can't see users with custom role in drop down for author of post.

Anybody have idea how to append my users there?

Comment: What are the capabilities for that custom user role?

Comment: I set next capabilities:

s:6:"single";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Single";s:12:"capabilities";a:8:{s:4:"read";b:1;s:10:"edit_posts";b:1;s:10:"edit_pages";b:1;s:17:"edit_others_posts";b:1;s:12:"create_posts";b:1;s:17:"manage_categories";b:0;s:13:"publish_posts";b:1;s:16:"enable_cometchat";b:1;}}

Publish post is true

Answer (score 0):

please try this plugin , with the help of this plugin you can assign any types of capabilities to your user , you can also create custom role too.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/